# Windows Batch File to Find String in Filename

Tags: windows, batch-file, find

How can i find the String in filename using a windows batch command. All systems generated files has dates in the file name like "xxx_2014-04-11_v1.xml",  I want to read the file name to verify date before performing any other operation. How  can this be achieved?

Comment: What kind of "verification" are you doing?

Comment: `Seeing code you are using` to get the filename would help.  We don't know if you are using `delayed expansion` and if it is `inside a loop` etc.

Comment: Your question is exceedingly vague. What string are you looking for, and what does that mean? Do you want to extract a substring? What type of validation do you want to perform? Edit your question to give example file names and expected result. Also, show what you have tried that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
for /f "delims=_ tokens=2" %%a in ('echo "xxx_2014-04-11_v1.xml"') do echo %%a
```